# DynamicProxy using dynamic/DLR

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, dynamic-language-runtime

I'm trying to make a dynamic proxy as a wrapper for an existing library, the goal is to 
handle all operations (properties access, members access, method calls, ...) with an 
existing object through a dynamic dispatch. I might need that for cross-cutting concerns, 
like better error handling, logging or access control for this object.

I came up with creating a `dynamic` wrapper for an existing object that implements 
`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface, however parsing all the `Expressions` by 
implementing my own `DynamicMetaObject` seems to be cumbersome!

The other solution is to inherit from the `DynamicObject` class to do the heavy lifting for 
me, but again there are dozen of virtual methods, which I don't exactly know how to 
override! I guess I only know what `TrySetMember`, `TryGetMember` and `TryInvokeMember` 
methods do or how to implement them, but there are lots of other methods that I don't know 
how to use!

```
public class DynamicProxy : DynamicObject
{
    private object Value;

    public DynamicProxy(object value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;      // get proxy object value using reflection
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        // set proxy object value using reflection
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        result = null;      // call proxy object method using reflection
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        return base.TryInvoke(binder, args, out result);
    }

    public override bool TryDeleteIndex(DeleteIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes)
    {
        // What to do here?
    }

    public override bool TryDeleteMember(DeleteMemberBinder binder)
    {
        // What to do here?
    }

    public override bool TryUnaryOperation(UnaryOperationBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        // What to do here?
    }

    // ... Other virtual methods of DynamicObject
}
```

So my question is: Is there any open source library that fully covers `DynamicObject` or at 
the very least fully implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface? Can somebody point 
out an overview of `DynamicObject` virtual methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to override all methods of `DynamicObject`, just `TryGetMember` and `TrySetMember` is enough in most cases. `DynamicObject` have default implementations for all methods, and you can implement only methods you want to change

`DynamicObject` is a class that implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, so use it if your wrapper doesn't have to have any other base class

Implementing `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` would be a bit boring, but if you however will decide to do that, take a look how it is implemented in `DynamicObject` with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)

Comment: How about Method calls? Indexers? Constructors?

Comment: DynamicObject implements all methods by default,and you only need to override methods you need

Comment: The proxy objects are actually POCO objects already defined in an existing assembly, so I cant not change their base class. Gonna check ILSpy to see how `DynamicObject` is implemented. It's all because of the poor documentation of `DynamicObject` and `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` in MSDN

Answer (score 1):

I have an opensource framework ImpromptuInterface (in nuget), that has an abstract class [ImpromptuForwarder](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageDynamic#ImpromptuForwarder) that is a [DynamicObject subclass](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/source/browse/ImpromptuInterface/src/Dynamic/ImpromptuForwarder.cs) that's base implementation just forwards the calls using the dlr for properties, methods and events and indexers to a Target.

It also has a lot of other fun dlr proxying stuff too, including [static interface typing to dynamic implementations](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageBasic), [curring methods](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageCurry), [late bound type static method proxy](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/source/browse/ImpromptuInterface/src/Dynamic/ImpromptuLateLibraryType.cs).